# main doesn't consider a for-loop

Tags: c, for-loop, program-entry-point

I can't get out of this:

In the following code, if I choose option `1`, I let the code begin asking the input described on  `1/* InserimentoNaviP1 */`; but when the program runs, without error in compiling, the function `main()` avoids it; the first `printf` is

```
("P1: inserisci la riga dove fare fuoco: ");
```

Can you please help me?

Below a part of the code (I cannot insert it all)

```
main() {
    scanf("%d", &a);    
    switch (a) {    
      case 1: 
        printf("Che vinca il migliore!! \n");
        break;
        return 0; // Unreachable code...
    }               
       
    Sleep(1000);
    InizializzaGrigliaP1();
    InizializzaGrigliaP2();   

    /* InserimentoNaviP1 */    
    for (r = 0; r < righe; r++) {          
        for (c = 0; c < colonne; c++) {
            printf("Inserisci  riga %d e colonna %d: ", r, c);
            scanf("%d", &grigliaP1[r][c]);
        }                       
            
        if (grigliaP1[r][c] == 1) {
            printf("nave inserita!\n");
            contnum_naviP1++;
            printf("restano da inserire %d navi!\n", P1_num_navi - contnum_naviP1);
        }      
    }

    for (t = 0;; t++) {
        //SparaP1
        {
            printf("P1: inserisci la riga dove fare fuoco: ");
           
            system("pause");
        }
    } // added
} // added
```

Comment: Note - since we don't know what value `righe` or `colonne` contains, it is very possible that the first set of for loops are skipped (if `righe` or `colonne` were <= 0), which would cause the behavior you are seeing.  Obviously, your code is incomplete so we cannot help more without actual working code.

Comment: Also, adding warnings to your code will point out things like the `return 0;` being unreachable and such.

Comment: The definition of `a` is not shown in your code.  Is it an `int`?

Comment: *"Below a part of the code (I cannot insert it all)"* Belive me, that's a great opportunity to exercise yourself into writing a [mre]. Focusing on a smaller part your code will help you (or us) in finding the issue.

Comment: hi @MichaelDorgan, righe and colonne are values inserted by the user, so are initialized at 0

Comment: @WilliamPursell yes int a;

Comment: @Bob__ totally agree :)

Comment: If those values are 0, then the for loops immediately exit.  Be sure to set them to the number of rows and columns before entering the main body.

Comment: @Micheal Dorgan thanks, that was the issue. In reshaping the code i have postponed that phase, now it works properly